# Wireshark filter for different interface

Tags: wireshark

I know that before capturing packets, I can select specific interface.

I wonder is there any filter to distinguish different interfaces after I capture packets?

That is, at the beginning, I capture packets of all interfaces.

After that, I can using "some filter" for different interfaces.

Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Linux cooked" capture mode doesn't distinguish in any way between packets from different interfaces. You can only filter the results by IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Since Wireshark 1.8 and while using the pcap-ng capture format you can use `frame.interface_id`. It is a number of the interface the frame was captured from. To map the number to the actual interface see the Statistics > Summary window. The first interface in the table has number 0 and the other follow.

I tested this on Ubuntu 12.04.3 (kernel 3.2.0-57), Wireshark 1.10.3.

For additional details see:

- [Wireshark-users: Re: [Wireshark-users] Wireshark V1.8.0 - analysing dual NIC capture](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201206/msg00085.html)
- [PcapNg](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/PcapNg)
- [Display Filter Reference: Frame](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a bit when you are using Linux cooked capture, using the SLL filter. Take a look at http://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL, and look for options in the Filter Expression window.

Although you can't exactly filter each interface, you can for example select the type of interface with 'sll.hatype == 1' for ethernet or 'sll.hatype == 512' for ppp interfaces (see values in if_arp.h header file).